# Array.Copy exception

Tags: c#, arrays, exception

I'm trying to increase size of array using `Array`.Copy C# built in `static` method.
Code is as follows:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int Capacity { get; set; }
    private int Size { get; set; }
    private int[] Nodes { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Capacity = 5;
        Size = 0;
        Nodes = new int[Capacity];
    }

    public void EnlargeIfNeeded()
    {
        if (Size == Capacity)
        {
            Capacity = 2 * Capacity;
            Array.Copy(Nodes, Nodes, Capacity);
        }
    }
}
```

It throws the following exception, when method `EnlargeIfNeeded()` is invoked:

> system.argument.exception: Source array was not long enough. Check
>   srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bound

Is it OK to use the following? My unit tests are passing OK, now:

```
    public void EnlargeIfNeeded()
    {
        if (Size == Capacity)
        {
            Capacity = 2 * Capacity;
            var dest = new int[Capacity];
            Array.Copy(Nodes, dest, Capacity/2);
            Nodes = dest;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you expect doubling a field `Capacity` to influence the actual capacity of the array `Nodes`? `Array.Copy` certainly does not do that.

Comment: Yes, my final intention is to double array capacity.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation for `Array.Copy` very carefully. You're not using it properly at the moment. You might want to use `Nodes = Array.Resize(Nodes, Capacity)` instead. But why are you basically reinventing `List<T>`?

Comment: Thanks, I'm not wanting to re-invent anything. I'm just trying to use only language built-in basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to resize your array, using an List collection could be a better approach, since it natively implements the array resize in a more effective way.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: My requirement is to use an array (int[]). Thanks, for suggestion.

Comment: So... Array.Resize(ref Nodes, Capacity);

Comment: Sorry, but Array.Resize(ref Nodes, Capacity) can not be used. Compile time error: ref keyword can not be used in property or indexer

Comment: try to encapsulate your array outside from the property, like: private int[] Nodes;

Comment: hmm... int[] Nodes should be an internal field of my class. It think we could not do it. I guess you mean to use a 'field' not 'a property'. Thanks a lot!

Comment: private int[] Nodes is different from private int[] Nodes { get; set; }, which is a property.

Comment: Yeah, but you could use another property to expose your data. And the internal field to manipulate the data.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll just want [`Array.Resize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx).

In addition, I would suggest getting rid of the `Capacity` member, so you have less state to take care of yourself. (nb: the below is dry-coded, so YMMV.)

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int Size { get; set; }
    private int[] Nodes { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Size = 0;
        Nodes = new int[5];
    }

    public void EnlargeIfNeeded()
    {
        if (Size == Nodes.Length)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref Nodes, Nodes.Length * 2);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: added the missing `ref` keyword.

Comment: Using your code, I'm getting an error: Argument 1 must be passed with 'ref' keyword, at line: Array.Resize(Nodes, Nodes.Length * 2)

Comment: @JoanDimko: Good catch. Added the keyword.

Comment: You should make int[] Nodes a field